# JS - How to remove items from Array that are present on other Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have two array with the following structure:

- Array A: [[1, 10], [2, 4], [5,22], [3, 10]]
- Array B: [2, 5]

The result array should be:

- Array C: [[1, 10], [3, 10]]

I'm trying to use *includes()* but it's very slow when I have big arrays. What is best solution to remove items on this case? Here is what I'm trying:

```
let activeCSs = css.filter(cs => !vacant_css.includes(cs[0]));
```

Comment: Convert the second array to a `Set`.

Comment: Your arrays must be pretty big! Are both A and B big or is one of them much bigger than the other?

Comment: @FelixKling convert Array B to Set?

Comment: @LuanNico probably is pretty big..i don't have case test to see the size because it's an exercise from hackerrank

Comment: The array you want check whether it contains a value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want only to check the first element of the inner arrays, you could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the check.

```js
var arrayA = [[1, 10], [2, 4], [5, 22], [3, 10]],
    arrayB = [2, 5],
    setB = new Set(arrayB)
    result = arrayA.filter(([v]) => !setB.has(v));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It’s not clear whether the op actually needs to check every element. But that aside, using a set reduces the complexity of the inner check from O(n^2) to O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using reduce and filter

```js
var A = [
  [1, 10],
  [2, 4],
  [5, 22],
  [3, 10]
];
var B = [2, 5];
var result = B.reduce((carry, current) => carry.filter(list => !list.includes(current)), A);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Assumption: base on the `!vacant_css.includes(cs[0]))` code in the question, the comparison is for each integer in ArrayB to the first integer in each array contained in arrayA.   `arrayA[x][y] === arrayB[z]`.  Coded to solve that problem.*

Poster mentions in comments this is from an exercise, so pretty good bet they were looking for time complexity sensitive solution...

I am not a big O expert (yeah, I hear it), but I think my answer ends up something like: O(n log n) + O(n log n) + O(n).  It is not immediately clear to me what the Set based answer would result in big O. O(n) * O(n) + whatever the Set(arrayB) costs I think?

```
let arrayA = [[1, 10], [2, 4], [5, 22], [3, 10]]
let arrayB = [2, 5]
arrayA.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
arrayB.sort((a, b) => a - b)

let i = 0
let j = 0
let arrayAnswer = []

while (i<arrayA.length&&j<arrayB.length) {
  let d = arrayA[i][0]-arrayB[j];
  console.log(`i ${i} j ${j} d ${d}`)
  if (d === 0) {
    i++
  } else if (d<0) {
    arrayAnswer.push(arrayA[i])
    i++    
  } else {
    j++
  }
}

console.log(arrayAnswer)
```

Warning:  This code is not tested for edge cases and is janky and old school.